# How to set fdtype of FInfo in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, file, cocoa, xcode5.1

I have a function which checks the fdtype of a file and does some operation.

```
-(BOOL)isTextFile:(NSString*)filePath
{
    FInfo*theInfo;
FSCatalogInfotheCatInfo;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] catalogInfo:&theCatInfo ofFileAtPath:filePath withBitmap:kFSCatInfoFinderInfo];
theInfo = (FInfo*)&theCatInfo.finderInfo;


if (theInfo->fdType == 'TEXT')
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
}
```

I want to know how can we set the fdtype of a file.
we have a requirement where we need to check if the file has extension .txt based on which I need to set the fdtype of the file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set directly the value into the variable.

```
theInfo->fdType = 'TEXT';
```

This will make sure that the fdType is set and can be used further.